# how to preserve scroll location after onClick event?

Tags: javascript, html, anchor

I've created a list of geography questions for kids.  The URL is as follows:

http://phillipmfeldman.org/history/silly_geography.html#

I initial set the display styles to "none" to hide the answers.  When a link is clicked, the display style of the corresponding element is changed to "" to unhide it.  This works well, except that the scroll location is not preserved.  I created a function (`scroll_to`) to set the scroll position to a specific element and tried calling this the final `onClick` action, but it doesn't work.  I suspect that the reason for this is that the scroll position is being reset after the onClick has been processed.  Any advice will be appreciated.

Phillip

Comment: I can't see "scroll_to" function

Comment: I removed it.  The `scroll_to` function looked like this:

function scroll_to(ID) {
   window.location.hash= ID;
}

Answer (score 0):

In your anchor `<a>` tag the attribute `href="#"` this is causing the issue. Please set the attribute href to blank string like: `href=""`

Comment: When I set href to a null string, clicking on the answer link has no effect at all.  This is not an acceptable solution.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a non-ideal but workable solution that has two components:

(1) I specify an anchor (ID) in each question.

(2) Clicking on the link for the answer sets the scroll point to the anchor associated with the question.

(This solution is non-ideal because the display still jumps, but the question and answer are guaranteed to remain visible). An example follows:

```
<li><p id="Q1">(1 point) Name a city in France where mean people are scarce.
<a href="#Q1" onClick="toggle('A1')">Give up or check your answer.
```